# Откуда взять модуль win32com.client?

Tags: python, модульность, база-данных, sql

Выдает ошибку

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\ThirdTask\connect.py", line 1, in <module>
    import kinterbasdb, win32com.client
ImportError: No module named win32com.client
```

Откуда взять модуль win32com.client?

Comment: его нету в стандартной поставке, нужно установить, скачать файлы модуля и в них сделать команду python setup.py install

Answer (score 10, accepted):

А погуглить было трудно?

[Здесь](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pywin32) скачиваем pywin32 и устанавливаем

например, для версии 2.7:

```
pip install pywin32-220.1-cp27-cp27m-win32.whl
```

**если не захочет ставиться**, то качаем [отсюда](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20220/) и ставим в папку с нужной версией интерпретатора.

Comment: Погуглил, нашёл этот пост, поставил. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

Ситуацией на 2023 год все вообще легко:

`python -m pip install --upgrade pywin32`

Если еще чего-то не хватает, то дополнительно:

`python Scripts/pywin32_postinstall.py -install`

Взято из официальной документации ([тык](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32#installing-via-pip))